# MySql.Data vs MySql.Data.CF

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

Can some on explain the difference between the libraries :

MySql.Data and MySql.Data.CF.

Can they co-exist in the same ASP.NET Website project ?

They both contain the same namespace and classes which causes ambiguity.

We've faced some cases where communicating with MySQL works only using MySql.Data and throws an exception using MySql.Data.CF, and vice-versa.

Any Clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Are you referencing your dlls from the GAC or from your bin directory?

Comment: Both are referenced from the bin of projects referenced to the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MySql.Data.CF` namespace is for the compact framework edition of the `MySql.Data` namespace. You should only use that if you're developing for Windows Phone or Windows Mobile (hopefully not Windows Mobile anymore).

Your bin directory should have a similar structure:

> MySql.Data.dll
>   MySql.Data.Entity.dll
>   MySql.Web.dll
>   MySql.VisualStudio.dll

In projects that I've used MySQL, I only reference `MySql.Data.dll` and not `MySql.Data.CF.dll`. Try removing the reference to `MySql.Data.CF` and see if that fixes the ambiguities.

Comment: We are intending to use one only, but my main question was about the difference between both DLLs. Our problem is that in somecases using MySQL.Data throws an runtime exception, trying to execute any query, and we have to use MySQL.Data.CF, and vice-versa.

Comment: I've updated my answer explaining the difference between the two namespaces.